# Linux fopen and fclose

Tags: linux, file, fopen, fclose

Assume that I have fopen'ed a file with "rx" flag.

Q1. What's the difference using "r" and "rx"?

Q2. Is it possible that fclose could fail even if I fopen'ed a file with "rx" flag?
I've heard that most of the reason for fclose's failure is due to the 'flushing' write operation.

Q3. Assume that I am a process of uid/euid 1000. If my forked child process execve's to a 'setuid' binary (owned by user 1001), will it be possible for parent process to access the opened file descriptor(file owned by 1001 with -r-------- permission) of child process?? If its impossible, exactly how can this be prevented?

Q4. Could Q1, 2, 3 be differ depending on the glibc / Linux kernel / Arch versions?

I'd like to understand this matter specifically in programmer's view.
thank you in advance.

Comment: Most of these are answered in the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html)...

Comment: I'm not sure you can combine `x` with `r` - how would it make sense to open a file for reading, but fail if the file already exists? Check the return value of `fopen()`...

Comment: I've already read the man page before writing this thread... they do not answer my questions in detail. fopen with rx flag works fine. but I don't know the difference with r flag

Comment: Are you talking about mode parameter to fopen(3) or permission bits on files (showed on your terminal when doing `ls -l` for example)? If you are talking about permission bits, the difference when it comes to fopen(3) is zero, as the `x` means execution bit (see e.g. http://www.perlfect.com/articles/chmod.shtml). The execution bit does not matter when you open a file for reading (or close it afterwards).

Comment: oh...!! I meant fopen("file", "rx"); not the file permission bit.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

I think `fopen("file", "rx")` is not correct because there is no mode called `"rx"` and a combination between `"r"` and `"x"` is not legal to use.